# Ansible 'lineinfile' module: 'state: absent' is not removing a line

Tags: ansible

This is the file **`netcfg.yaml`**

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s31:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses: [192.168.1.221/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
    enp12s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.1/24
    enp8s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
    enp9s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.16.1/24
```

I'm trying to remove 2 lines from `enp0s31:`

```yaml
      addresses: [192.168.1.221/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
```

Below is my code:

```yaml
- name: Remove addresses
  lineinfile:
    path: /tmp/netcfg.yaml
    line: '      addresses: '
    insertafter: '      dhcp4: yes'
    firstmatch: True
    state: absent

- name: remove gateway4 field
  lineinfile:
    path: /tmp/netcfg.yaml
    line: '      gateway4: '
    firstmatch: True
    state: absent
```

It is not removing the lines, though no errors when I run the playbook.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For a YAML document like that it makes more sense to read it into in-memory data structures, modify the structure of the document, and then serialize it back out.

Unfortunately, Ansible isn't great at modifying deeply nested structures, but we can work around that with custom filter plugins.

For example, if we put the following in `filter_plugins/json_delete.py`:

```py
import jmespath

def json_delete(v, ptr, k):
    res = jmespath.search(ptr, v)
    del res[k]
    return v

class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {'json_delete': json_delete}
```

Then we can write a playbook like this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: read netcfg
      include_vars:
        file: netcfg.yaml
        name: netcfg

    - name: write updated config
      copy:
        content: >-
          {{
            netcfg|
            json_delete('network.ethernets.enp0s31', 'addresses')|
            json_delete('network.ethernets.enp0s31', 'gateway4')|
            to_nice_yaml(indent=2)
          }}
        dest: netcfg.yaml
```

Which produces the output:

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s31:
      dhcp4: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
    enp12s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.0.1/24
      dhcp4: false
    enp8s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.1/24
      dhcp4: false
    enp9s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.16.1/24
      dhcp4: false
  renderer: NetworkManager
  version: 2
```

Comment: thank you! but, we are not using any plugins in our current project. Could you please help with ansible lineinfile module

Comment: This solution is really great. Simple, easy to understand and to maintain. It should become the accepted answer.